# Can I use Eneloop batteries in my thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, battery

I have this LuxPro thermostat http://www.luxproproducts.com/pdfs/spec_pdfs/PSD010Bc_NL_ENG_Manual.pdf

There's a warning in the very first section that says to use only Duracell or Energizer Alkaline batteries.

Will there be a problem if I use Eneloops?

Comment: it may be a partnership between them for increased sales for the battery people.

Answer (score 2):

Eneloop batteries are NiMH which has a normal voltage of 1.2V vs. 1.5V for an alkaline batteries. Your thermostat uses two batteries so the Eneloops will generate 2.4V instead of 3V for fresh alkalines. At a worst case, the thermostat will not work (or report low batteries with fully charged batteries). Best case, the batteries will last for a short time.

As for specifying brand name alkalines, it's probably a partnership as @ratchetfreak suggested. They may also be trying to avoid customer dissatisfaction when cheap, off-brand batteries work poorly or last for a short time.

Comment: It may not even be a partnership -- it may be a matter of simplifying the support problem. "I tried this with Gibblefrotz batteries and it didn't work." Rather than trying to work through what this battery they've never heard of actually is, this lets them just tell people "only the cited batteries are supported; go out and buy a set of those, and call us back if you still have problems."

Comment: Comparing voltages of different battery chemistries is a little more complicated than just 1.2 vs 1.5 V. The voltage is largely dependent on the current, which is why NiMH batteries can maintain voltage better than alkalines in high-drain applications.

Comment: @HenryJackson - true. However, in the OP's case, the thermostat is a low-current application.

Comment: Perhaps. Personally I think @keshlam is probably right that it's just to cut down on support troubleshooting.